# Duplicate files copied in APK AUTHORS

Tags: android, data-binding

when i am learning DataBinding ,i got the error like this`Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK AUTHORS
>       File1: D:\WorkTools\Android_studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\external\lombok\lombok-ast\0.2.3\lombok-ast-0.2.3.jar
>       File2: D:\WorkTools\Android_studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\external\lombok\lombok-ast\0.2.3\lombok-ast-0.2.3.jar`
>   please help me!

Comment: post your `build.gradle`

Comment: 'dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
  compile 'com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc0'
}dataBinding {
    enabled = true
  }'this is my module's build.gradle

Comment: did you solve this problem? I have the exact same issue now